# How to change symbol color in Angular 4 pipes?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Is there a way to change the color of Angular 4 pipes symbol? I want to make the dollar symbol lighter color, for example.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpEml.png)

This price is parsed with **currency** pipe:

```
currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow':'1.2-4'
```

Comment: How would that even work? You can't do that. The output from the pipe will end up in a single element, with one style. You'd have to put the symbol in a separate span or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [decimal pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) and you put your own `<span>$</span>` before it.

Untested example:

```
<div>
  <span class="currency">$</span> {{ data.cost | number }}
</div>

.currency {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that will be the way. Thanks